# Converting Excel Indirect Match formula to VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this template and I'm reverse engineering it to build some validation for an ERP system. It's using this formula to find a cell position within a named range, how can I convert this to VBA? I tried to store it in a string by running the formula but it didn't return any result. I would much rather perform this function in VB but I am unaware of how to do so.

```
rngFind = rngSearch.Formula = "=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""Hidden13303089_"", MATCH(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL(""address"")), 0, -1, 1, 1), Hidden13303084, 0)))"
```

I wrote a search function but it doesn't return the relative address of the cell within the range, it returns the row number of the in the entire sheet.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: `set rngfind = rngsearch.find("yourvalue")`  Then you can do what you want to the rngfind object

Comment: I used the rngsearch.find the value and it returns the rows address in the sheet, but I need to return the row address in the range. How do I do that?

Comment: subtract the row address of the first row in your range with a plus 1?